# Why do I need of reference for the to_string function?

Tags: string, rust, integer

I am new to Rust. While trying to concatenate string literals and integers, I was given many errors because of the "to_string" function. After that realized that I needed to put a reference/ampersand (&) in front of an integer. However, I cannot understand why. Can you explain why I need to put a reference sign in front of an integer for the to_string function? I wrote an example code below.

```
fn main() {
    let number = 42;
    let text = "The answer is";
    let result = text.to_owned() + " " + &number.to_string();
    println!("{}", result);
}
```

Comment: cause add on this case is not implemented for String but only for &str

Comment: better code https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0b72847453184d0344f13e34fc12721f

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the `+` operator for strings take `String` and `&str` and not `String` and `String`, as [that is what the `std::ops::Add` implementation takes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.72.0/src/alloc/string.rs.html#2322).

This is because to concatenate a string efficiently, you need one of the strings  to be owned, so we can reuse its buffer and possibly avoid an allocation, but you don't need the other string to be owned, a reference is enough. Technically, there is no reason why `impl Add<String> for &str` can't be provided too, it just doesn't exist.